# How do I use the grab and retrieve open cv functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, image, opencv, camera

I'm currently using opencv with python to run two webcams. These webcams will each take a picture. I'd like to run them on separate threads in order to sync the pictures as closely as possible. I'm using videocapture::grab() and videocapture::retreive() but I'm not sure if I'm using them properly because it seems like retrieve works on it's own when I comment out the grab function. 
Below is my code.

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import cv2
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
count = 0
video_capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
video_capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

#camera1
class myThread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, device):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        # Get lock to synchronize threads
       # threadLock.acquire()
        camCapture(self.name, 1)
        # Free lock to release next thread
       # threadLock.release()

def camCapture(threadName, device):

    if video_capture1.grab():
        print "frame grabbed1"

#camera2    
class myThread2 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, device):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        # Get lock to synchronize threads
       # threadLock.acquire()
        camCapture2(self.name, 2)
        # Free lock to release next thread
       # threadLock.release()

def camCapture2(threadName, device):
    if video_capture2.grab():
        print "frame grabbed2"



# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread1(1, "Thread-1", count)
thread2 = myThread2(2, "Thread-2", count)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()


ret, image1 = video_capture1.retrieve()
ret, image2 = video_capture2.retrieve()
cv2.imwrite("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\camOne" + str(count) + ".bmp", image1)
cv2.imwrite("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\camTwo" + str(count) + ".bmp", image2)
```

Am I using the correct syntax with the grab and retrieve commands? I just wanted to make sure before I test these cameras.

I'm also saving these photo's as a Bitmap image because I want them to be as close to the raw formatting that they can be. Is this my best option?